# S4 Classes: Multiple types per slot

Tags: r, r-s4

Is it possible to create an S4 class, where one or more of the slots can be of multiple classes? For example. Let's say that you had a situation where data could be either a vector, or a data.frame.

```
exampleClass <- setClass("exampleClass",
    representation(raw=c("data.frame","numeric","character"),
    anotherSlot=c("data.frame","numeric"))
```

Or, is this the type of situation where defining a sub-class / super-class becomes necessary?

PS: Searching for a useful tutorial on S4 classes produces limited results. Links to a good tutorial on S4 class creation/usage/documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Things with slots are S4 classes.

Comment: Not just that, everything you show is related to the S4 method mechanism.

Comment: Could've been worse; you could have said "R5 classes"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

R has 'class unions', so

```
setOldClass("data.frame")
setClassUnion("data.frameORvector", c("data.frame", "vector"))
```

The class `data.frameORvector` is virtual, so can't be instantiated but can be used in other slots (`representation=`), as a contained class (`contains=`), and for dispatch

```
A = setClass("A", 
        representation=representation(x="data.frameORvector"))


> A(x=1:3)
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
[1] 1 2 3

> A(x=data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:1))
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 2
3 3 1
```

Methods can be tricky to implement because all you know is that the slot contains one of the parent types of the class union.

```
setGeneric("hasa", function(object) standardGeneric("hasa"))
setMethod("hasa", "data.frameORvector", function(object) typeof(object@x))

> hasa(A(x=1:5))
[1] "integer"
> hasa(A(x=data.frame(y=1:5)))
[1] "list"
```

I actually find the documentation on `?Classes`, `?Methods`, `?setClass`, and friends helpful. Hadley Wickham has a [tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) (the example on this page isn't that strong, it instantiates `Person`, whereas conceptually one would write a `People` to exploit R's vectorization strengths) and there is a section in this recent [Bioconductor course](http://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2012/Seattle-Oct-2012/). I don't think either goes in to detail about class unions.

Comment: Martin Morgan -- Your terrific answers to so many real R programming questions here on SO are a great addition to this community. Just wanted to give you props and thanks for that.

Comment: Agree, and previous answers on S4 questions have been very well explained.