# Is it possible to not set types for s4 slots

Tags: r, r-s4

## What I want to achieve

In order to build a generic framework i would like to build an s4 class with a slot that could be of any type. Is it possible? And if so how?

## What I have found so far

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002200/s4-classes-multiple-types-per-slot) question that adress the multiple types problem. But I would like to make it possible for any types not just some predefined types.

## Example:

```
setClass("foo",
         representation(
           anything = "..."
         )
)

# I would like to be able to perform all of these
new("foo", anything = 1)
new("foo", anything = "a")
new("foo", anything = data.frame())
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like:

```
setClass("hi", slots = c(slot1 = "ANY"))
```

The use of `ANY` is actually documented in the help.